# Remove all cocoapod dependencies from a project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, cocoapods

So I have a large Xcode project with Obj-C and Swift code, with many many cocoapods dependencies.

But my developer of choice doesn't work with cocoapod dependencies.
I know this is a bit strange but he just doesn't want to set up his Mac with pods and it's not negotiable with him (also switching devs is not an option).

So...my question.
Is it possible to remove all cocoapod dependencies and still have the project compile and run as it currently does?
I have a feeling people will say - it depends on your project.
But if I could just get a rough "Yes it is possible" or "No it is always impossible" that would be great.
And if it is possible, how does one go about starting such a task?

---

I don't know if this will help but here's a list of all the current Cocoapod dependencies in the project:

- pod 'Countly'
- pod 'CocoaLumberjack'
- pod 'Fabric'
- pod 'Crashlytics'
- pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.0'
- pod 'MBProgressHUD'
- pod 'CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout', '~> 0.9'
- pod 'pop', '~> 1.0'
- pod 'TwitterKit'
- pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
- pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
- pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
- pod 'FBSDKMessengerShareKit'
- pod 'Inapptics'
- pod 'Firebase/Core'
- pod 'Firebase/Auth'
- pod 'Firebase/Storage'
- pod 'FirebaseUI/Storage'
- pod 'Firebase/Database'
- pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
- pod 'SwiftKeychainWrapper'
- pod 'DeviceKit', '~> 1.0'
- pod 'WSCoachMarksView'
- pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift'
- pod 'FLAnimatedImage', '~> 1.0'
- pod 'GBDeviceInfo'
- pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 4.0'
- pod 'SDWebImage/GIF'
- pod 'MagazineLayout'
- pod 'Toucan'

Comment: If you commit your dependencies to your repo, he should be able to work on the app without having cocoapods installed. Any changes would have be done by somebody who has it installed, but it will be a lot better than manually keeping all files up to date.

Answer (score 3):

You can remove the cocoapods but in order for your project to build, You will have to add the dependances to your project one by one.

Personally I don't recommend doing that. it's a lot of work and if you changed your developer in the future you might need to re-add them once more.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

How do I go about adding dependencies to your project one by one?

And why do you say I may need to re-add the dependencies again in the future if I change developer?

Comment: For adding dependencies you can check this apple tutorial at:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/adding_package_dependencies_to_your_app

You will need to re-add the dependencies if any other developer will wish to work on it since the most iOS developer will prefer the use of cocopoads over manual dependancies

Answer (score 1):

It's not recommended, but as you said it's not possible to switch developer at this stage. Just deintegrate the project from cocoapods, and then after manually copy paste your require files/library to your project.

To Deintegrate Pod just go to your project folder using Terminal. and Type

pod deintegrate

after that Manually copy/paste library files to your project in Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question your developer doesn't have experience in cocoapods that's why he does not want it. I tell you if you remove your cocoapods dependencies library while your app is using those dependencies, it will not work. That's why it is call dependencies because your app is dependent in those libraries. Unless your app does not use those libraries anymore you can remove it but I guess that's not the case.

Your developer should have an alternate dependency manager, other than cocoapods there are carthage and Swift Package manager.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. But where your app is using those dependencies, it will show error.

Just follow this two steps to remove.

1. remove/comment out all dependencies. For comment out just add # before every dependency.(i.e #pod 'Countly')
2. Install pod again with "pod install" command.